# c# draw a dot for each array point

Tags: c#, winforms

This program should make an array and according to the values in it, it should draw different colored dots.

First it creates a blank map (array).
After that it fills the map with obstacle(s).
In the end it should represent the obstacles graphically on the imagebox but it doesn't do that.

What is the error?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public byte[,] ObstacleGenerator(byte[,] map, byte leftTopX, byte leftTopY, byte rightBottomX, byte rightBottomY)
    {
        // akadályt építi fel
        for (int i = leftTopX; i <= rightBottomX; i++)
        {
            for (int j = leftTopY; j <= rightBottomY; j--)
            {
                map[i, j] = 1;
            }
        }
        return map;
    }
    public byte[,] MapGenerator()
    {
        // a térképet építi fel
        byte[,] map = new byte[102-1, 102-1];
        for (int i = 0; i < map.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < map.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                //a térkép grafikusan nem látható pereme
                if (i == 0 || j == 0 || i == map.GetLength(0)-1 || j == map.GetLength(1)-1)
                {
                    map[i, j] = 253;
                    continue;
                }
                else
                //járható út
                {
                    map[i, j] = 0;
                }

            }
        }

        return map;
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            

    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        byte[,] map = MapGenerator();
        map = ObstacleGenerator(map, 20, 80, 40, 20);

        Brush aBrush = (Brush)Brushes.Black;
        Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
        for (int i = 0; i < map.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < map.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                //láthatatlan perem
                if (map[i,j] == 253)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                //út
                else if (map[i, j] == 0)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                //akadály
                else if (map[i, j] == 1)
                {
                    g.FillRectangle(aBrush, i, j, i, j);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Fixed some error.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public byte[,] ObstacleGenerator(byte[,] map, byte leftTopX, byte leftTopY, byte rightBottomX, byte rightBottomY)
    {
        // akadályt építi fel
        for (int i = leftTopX; i <= rightBottomX; i++)
        {
            for (int j = leftTopY; j <= rightBottomY; j--)
            {
                map[i, j] = 1;
            }
        }
        return map;
    }
    public byte[,] MapGenerator()
    {
        // a térképet építi fel
        byte[,] map = new byte[102-1, 102-1];
        for (int i = 0; i < map.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < map.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                //a térkép grafikusan nem látható pereme
                if (i == 0 || j == 0 || i == map.GetLength(0)-1 || j == map.GetLength(1)-1)
                {
                    map[i, j] = 253;                        
                }
                else
                //járható út
                {
                    map[i, j] = 0;
                }

            }
        }

        return map;
    }

    public void PictureBuilder(byte[,] map)
    {
        Brush aBrush = (Brush)Brushes.Black;
        Graphics g = e.Graphics(); 
        for (int i = 0; i < map.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < map.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                //láthatatlan perem
                if (map[i, j] == 0)
                {
                }
                //út
                else if (map[i, j] == 253)
                {
                }
                //akadály
                else if (map[i, j] == 1)
                {
                    g.FillRectangle(aBrush, i, j, 1, 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            

    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        byte startX = 1;
        byte startY = 1;
        byte endX = 99;
        byte endY = 99;
        byte currentX = startX;
        byte currentY = startY;

        while (true)
        {

        }
        byte[,] map = MapGenerator();
        map = ObstacleGenerator(map, 20, 80, 40, 20);
        PictureBuilder(map);
    }
}
```

More fix.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public byte[,] ObstacleGenerator(byte[,] map, byte leftTopX, byte leftTopY, byte rightBottomX, byte rightBottomY)
    {
        // akadályt építi fel
        for (int i = leftTopX; i <= rightBottomX; i++)
        {
            for (int j = leftTopY; j <= rightBottomY; j--)
            {
                map[i, j] = 1;
            }
        }
        return map;
    }
    public byte[,] MapGenerator()
    {
        // a térképet építi fel
        byte[,] map = new byte[102-1, 102-1];
        for (int i = 0; i < map.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < map.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                //a térkép grafikusan nem látható pereme
                if (i == 0 || j == 0 || i == map.GetLength(0)-1 || j == map.GetLength(1)-1)
                {
                    map[i, j] = 253;                        
                }
                else
                //járható út
                {
                    map[i, j] = 0;
                }

            }
        }

        return map;
    }

    public void PictureBuilder(byte[,] map, Graphics g)
    {
        Brush aBrush = (Brush)Brushes.Black;
        for (int i = 0; i < map.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < map.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                //láthatatlan perem
                if (map[i, j] == 0)
                {
                }
                //út
                else if (map[i, j] == 253)
                {
                }
                //akadály
                else if (map[i, j] == 1)
                {
                    g.FillRectangle(aBrush, i, j, 1, 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Invalidate();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        byte startX = 1;
        byte startY = 1;
        byte endX = 99;
        byte endY = 99;
        byte currentX = startX;
        byte currentY = startY;

        byte[,] map = MapGenerator();
        map = ObstacleGenerator(map, 20, 80, 40, 20);

        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        PictureBuilder(map, g);

    }
}
```

Clos...

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public byte[,] ObstacleGenerator(byte[,] map, byte leftTopX, byte leftTopY, byte rightBottomX, byte rightBottomY)
    {
        // akadályt építi fel
        for (int i = leftTopX; i <= rightBottomX; i++)
        {
            for (int j = leftTopY; j <= rightBottomY; j--)
            {
                map[i, j] = 1;
            }
        }
        return map;
    }
    public byte[,] MapGenerator()
    {
        // a térképet építi fel
        byte[,] map = new byte[102-1, 102-1];
        for (int i = 0; i < map.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < map.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                //a térkép grafikusan nem látható pereme
                if (i == 0 || j == 0 || i == map.GetLength(0)-1 || j == map.GetLength(1)-1)
                {
                    map[i, j] = 253;                        
                }
                else
                //járható út
                {
                    map[i, j] = 0;
                }

            }
        }

        return map;
    }

    public void PictureBuilder(byte[,] map, Graphics g)
    {
        Brush aBrush = (Brush)Brushes.Black;
        for (int i = 0; i < map.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < map.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                //láthatatlan perem
                if (map[i, j] == 0)
                {
                }
                //út
                else if (map[i, j] == 253)
                {
                }
                //akadály
                else if (map[i, j] == 1)
                {
                    g.FillRectangle(aBrush, i, j, 1, 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        byte startX = 1;
        byte startY = 1;
        byte endX = 99;
        byte endY = 99;
        byte currentX = startX;
        byte currentY = startY;

        byte[,] map = MapGenerator();
        map = ObstacleGenerator(map, 20, 80, 40, 20);

        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        PictureBuilder(map, e.Graphics);

    }
```

Comment: I changed the g.FillRectangle(aBrush, i, j, i, j); into                     g.FillRectangle(aBrush, i, j, 1, 1); but no change

Comment: Replace `Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();` with `Graphics g = e.Graphics;` - ! At some point you should trigger the `Paint`  event by doing an `Invalidate`! Also: The `Paint` event belong to the `PictureBox` but `this` is the `Form`.

Comment: According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.painteventargs(v=vs.110).aspx it's actually a property e.Graphics, not a method

Comment: A typo, corrected..

Comment: I replaced the part you wrote but it throws the error "the name e does not exits in the current context". Also how exactly I trigger the Paint event?

Comment: a) you need to pass the Graphics object (`e.Graphics`) out to the `PictureBuilder` method! so add it to the signature to `PictureBuilder(byte[,] map, Graphics g)`!  Passing them around is fine just don't cache or create them..!To trigger the `Paint` you call `Invalidate()` on the PBox, maybe in the click..

Comment: I fixed that two, still nothing.

Comment: If you still don't see anything: Do set a breakpoint to the code, esp. the `FillRectangle` and check if it gets called and with which parameters!

Comment: Not a mistake you need to take care of now, but in general the Paint is only supposed to do/trigger the drawing. Setting up the data should happen outside and only when needed.

Comment: I catched a mistake. For some reason ObstacleGenerator doesn't return 1s at the array cells... But why.

Comment: Okay, it's finally working! Thank you very much for the help!